# Cluster points of a set.

Tags: metric-spaces

The question is to find all the cluster points of set $\{(x,y) | x>0, y>0\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. 
Just want to confirm my answer.
The answer is 
all the points of 1 st quadrant of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with points on the axes.
So, whether i found it correct? How shall I show this formally?

Comment: What is a cluster point?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right the set of cluster points of your given set is  $\{(x,y)  \in  \mathbb{R}^2 , x \geq 0, y \geq  0   \}$ (i.e. all the points of 1 st quadrant of  \mathbb{R}^2  with points on the axes). To prove this formaly you may use the definition used here  [Definition of cluster point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/853526/definition-of-cluster-point) .

Comment: @user5273591  you can read this also http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: he he, i got it. Sorry